# C++ How to store boost::asio::io_service as a class member

Tags: c++, boost

I´m building a service class and I would like to store the ioService as a class member. Here is the code:

**SocketServer.hpp**

```
class SocketServer {

    public:
        SocketServer(boost::asio::io_service& service);
        virtual ~SocketServer();

   private:
        boost::asio::io_service &ioService;
```

}

**SocketServer.cpp**

```
    SocketServer::SocketServer(boost::asio::io_service &service) :
        ioService(service) {}

    SocketServer::~SocketServer() {};
```

When compiling I´m getting the following error at the constructor implementation:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_socket_acceptor()’
```

I know `ioService` is non copyable, but I´m trying to store its reference, not copying the object itself.

What is happening here ? How can I solve that ?

Comment: Works for me. I doubt the code is the one producing the error. I hope, surroundings of class {} around members implementatins are just copy-paste typo.

Comment: It is a copy-past typo.... There are other member functions... I will delete them all and start again...

Comment: It really works. The problem is with another member variable - acceptor - that needs a constructor with parameters. Thanks for helping...

Comment: One related problem that might lead users to this page is not making the member variable (ioService above) a reference. That is, if you have `boost::asio::io_service ioService` without the `&` and try to `ioService(service)`, then you will get an error about using a deleted function (the copy constructor, since `service` cannot be copied).